# Can't use virt-manager after removing firewalld

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, firewalld, virt-manager

I accidentally ran a `sudo apt remove firewalld`, and now trying to use virt-manager to create a virtual machine shows the following message:

```
The name org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1 was not provided by any .service files
```

So, I decided to install the `firewalld` package again. Now, I'm getting the following error message:

```
internal error: firewalld is set to use the nftables backend, but the required firewalld 'libvirt' zone is missing. Either set the firewalld backend to 'iptables', or ensure that firewalld has a 'libvirt' zone by upgrading firewalld to a version supporting rule priorities (0.7.0+) and/or rebuilding libvirt with --with-firewalld-zone
```

`firewalld` is already on `0.9.1-1ubuntu1`, which is greater than 0.7.0, so I don't think there should be a problem with the version, but there is.

What would be the right solution, to return things as they were before removing `firewalld`?

The same errors appear when trying to run `virsh net-start default` manually.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 (Pop!_OS, which is why I had to move my question here)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in a comment by [Christian Ehrhardt](https://askubuntu.com/users/532139/christian-ehrhardt) in the original question, I changed

```
FirewallBackend=nftables
```

to

```
FirewallBackend=iptables
```

in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`.

and virt-manager works now.

It seems to be the default setting in Ubuntu but was reset when reinstalling the package.

However, I think it may not be the best solution since [`nftables` is supposedly better](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/), but if Ubuntu maintainers decided it's good, then I'll leave it like that for now; feel free to make better suggestions.